# Java with GUIs won't run

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hi I need help with Java on my mac. I've cleanly uninstalled all versions of Java and installed the Oracle JDK 1.8.0_202. I can do javac and java - and compile and run simple programs running in the console. However - when I try anything with a window - it hangs.

This includes all gui applications, java web starts and even the Java control panel won't launch - it simply stops responding and does not show anything.

This simply application also behaves the same:

```
import javax.swing.*;        

public class HelloWorldSwing {
/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I've tried reinstalling, rebooting, anything, and I still cannot get this simple program to run. I get no error messages in the terminal from where I run this - it just freezes.

Please help me troubleshoot this and get a working java setup.

I'm using a Macbook pro with Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: It has been a long time since I did something with Swing, so I might be wrong, but isn't the `invokeLater` meant to be used for long running task from the GUI thread? I think it shouldn't be used to invoke the GUI thread itself. Try just plainly invoking `createAndShowGUI()` from your main.

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked fine - showed me a window in the top left corner of the screen (you could easily miss it). You sure that you are simply just not missing it or its hidden behind other windows? Add         frame.setSize(1000, 1000); just for test to make sure.

Comment: @AndréStannek that is backwards. invokeLater runs the task on the EDT, you do not want long running tasks.

Comment: I'm sure - there is no window running, if I hover above the title bar up to the left with the program name it shows a spinner only which never stops and in the activity monitor it shows up as not responding. This is the same for all other GUI Java applications

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

Actually the real culprit is Display Link. If you ever have issues with Java and GUIs - it might be because you are using Display Link and the drivers are conflicting with Java. Only if your laptop screen is closed though.

See this for more information
https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66556

I hope this can help